# How can I make a continuously updating clock in a console application?

Tags: visual-studio, console, clock

com I am making a project for my programming exam, it will be an easy exam, and therefore I will only need to create a simple, basic console application. But, even though it is simple I really want to spice it up.
I have already made a simple clock:

```
        static public void clock()
    {
        Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0);
        Console.WriteLine("{0:D} {0:t}", DateTime.Now);
        Console.WriteLine("");
    }
```

I reference this method in the program by using the name "clock;" as shown here:

```
                        Console.Clear();
                    clock();
                    Console.WriteLine("┌───────────────────────────────────┐");
                    Console.WriteLine("|      Welcome to the Festival      |");
                    Console.WriteLine("└───────────────────────────────────┘");
```

Is it possible to add seconds to the clock, and make it update continuously, and do it in a simple way? A way that a newbie programmer could explain, as I would need to do that.
Thank you!

Comment: Your question will be improved, and will be considered by more people if you include code as text directly in your question, rather than requiring people visit an external site.

Comment: Thank you hatchet, I have re-done the question, with code snippets instead of imagery.

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely not foolproof, as there is no "easy" way to do this correctly...but it may do for your purposes:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task.Run(() => {
            while (true)
            {
                // save the current cursor position
                int x = Console.CursorLeft;
                int y = Console.CursorTop;

                // update the date/time
                Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0);
                Console.Write(DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd, MMMM d, yyyy hh:mm:ss"));

                // put the cursor back where it was
                Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y);

                // what one second before updating the clock again
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        });

        Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 2);
        Console.WriteLine("┌───────────────────────────────────┐");
        Console.WriteLine("|      Welcome to the Festival      |");
        Console.WriteLine("└───────────────────────────────────┘");

        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.Write("Please enter your name: ");
        string name = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Hello {0}!", name);

        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.Write("Press Enter to Quit...");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```